# Self-Classicafication Report - Is it need for US based registered companies?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-distribution

Regarding the apple's Self-classification report, My client has registered the company in the USA, but we are using "Https" in the application.

Do I need to submit the self-classification report?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must submit a self classification report to the US Government except your app qualifies for [one or more exemptions](https://bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/encryption/1-encryption-items-not-subject-to-the-ear) provided under [category 5 part 2](https://bis.doc.gov/index.php/documents/new-encryption/1652-cat-5-part-2-quick-reference-guide/file), of the [BIS Export Administration Regulation](https://www.bis.doc.gov/), including but not limited to apps that are:

- Specially designed for medical end-use
- Limited to intellectual
  property and copyright protection
- Limited to authentication, digital
  signature, or the decryption of data or files
- Specially designed and
  limited for banking use or "money transactions"; or Limited to
  "fixed" data compression or coding techniques

[Source](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devc3f64248f)